# Swift: Generic Function for Type Checking

Tags: swift, generics, types, typecasting-operator

noob question. This code has a lot of copy & paste for checking swift types. Is there a way to condense it into one generic function of some kind? Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import Foundation


let x: AnyObject = 42


if x is Int {
    print("x is Int")
}else {
    print("x is NOT Int")
}

if x is Double {
    print("x is Double")
}else {
    print("x is NOT Double")
}

if x is Float {
    print("x is Float")
}else {
    print("x is NOT Float")
}

if x is String {
    print("x is String")
}else {
    print("x is NOT String")
}

/* 
prints:
x is Int
x is Double
x is Float
x is NOT String
*/
```

Comment: i guess i forgot to clarify that ideally the function should be able to take an value of unknown type, then a "type", and check if the value is the type and return true of false. So basically (value, type) -> bool.

Comment: That's exactly what `is` does. Why do you want a function instead?

Comment: yes but as there's a lot of repeating code and i want to test for more types than just the four listed.

Comment: did my solution work for you? if not and you still need help, can you give an example of you need/want the function call to look like.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `dynamicType`:

```
print("x is \(x.dynamicType)")
```

In your case, since you explicit specified that `x` is an object (`AnyObject`) it is converted to `NSNumber` by the compiler. Technically, it's neither `Int`, nor `Double`, nor `Float`.

Comment: i think, that he needs also the 'else' part, but unfortunately in that case no 'shortcut' exists. generally .dynamicType should works with value types as well. struct S {}; let x: Any = S(); print("x is \(x.dynamicType)". the last sentence in your answer should be in BOLD!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're doing exactly, but just using `is` alone should work.

```
let x: AnyObject = 42

x is Int     // returns true
x is Double  // returns true
x is Float   // returns true
x is String  // returns false
```

but if you actually need a function for some other reason, then this works the exact same.

```
import Foundation

func checkType(value: AnyObject, type: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if type is Int {
        if value is Int {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else if type is Double {
        if value is Double {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else if type is Float {
        if value is Float {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else if type is String {
        if value is String {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}

let myVar: AnyObject = 42

checkType(myVar, Int())        // returns true
checkType(myVar, Double())     // returns true
checkType(myVar, Float())      // returns true
checkType(myVar, String())     // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the solution, it's actually quite simple:

```
let x = 42

func checkTypeOf<Value, Type> (value: Value, type: Type) {
    if value is Type {
        print("value is \(type.dynamicType)")
    }else {
        print("value is NOT \(type.dynamicType)")
    }
}

checkTypeOf(x, type: 0)
checkTypeOf(x, type: "")

/* 
prints:
value is Int
value is NOT String
*/
```

the thing is the "type" parameter needs to be a placeholder value, for example 0 for Int, or an empty string if checking String, so it's not the cleanest way to do it, but Swift's type inference makes it quite usable.